# Function analog range from lodash

Tags: javascript, function, range, lodash

The function must take three arguments:

**start** - is the number at which the sequence will start. This is an optional argument: by default, the function must start at 0.

**end** - number, end of the sequence. The function should stop before reaching this value.

**step** - number, step between elements in the sequence. This is an optional argument; the default is 1.

As a result, the function should return an array of numbers in the specified sequence.

Also, function calls should output the following values:

```js
1. range(4); // => [0, 1, 2, 3]

2. range(-4); // => [0, -1, -2, -3]

3. range(1, 5); // => [1, 2, 3, 4]

4. range(0, 20, 5); // => [0, 5, 10, 15]

5. range(0, -4, -1); // => [0, -1, -2, -3]

6. range(1, 4, 0); // => [1, 1, 1]

7. range(0); // => []
```

I wrote the following function

```js
function range (start, end, step = 1) {
  if (end === undefined && start !== undefined) {
    end = start;
    start = 0;
  }

  return Array(Math.ceil((end - start) / step)).fill(start).map((x, y) => x + y * step)
}

console.log(range(4)); // => [0, 1, 2, 3]
console.log(range(-4)); // => [0, -1, -2, -3]
console.log(range(1, 5)); // => [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(range(0, 20, 5)); // => [0, 5, 10, 15]
console.log(range(0, -4, -1)); // => [0, -1, -2, -3]
console.log(range(1, 4, 0)); // => [1, 1, 1]
console.log(range(0)); // => []
```

But tests numbered 2 and 6 do not pass, the console displays the error "Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length"

I have seen similar questions, but none of the options came up in order for all tests to pass successfully.
Please tell me how you can fix this error or how you can write a new function that performs this action. Thanks, I hope for your help

Comment: with the current logic test case 6 will never pass because `y * step` is always equals to 0, and will infinitely try to add numbers

Comment: I don't know you are not too far off.  I might suggest you break your logic into smaller steps as opposed to one giant chained togteher expression.  How do you know that you sized the array accurately?  if you pass in -4 then -4 should be the end and 0 be the start - right?   But -4 - 0 / 1 = -4 and not what I would expect a valid array size... also if the end is less than the start shouldn't the default step be negated?

Comment: ... just something to think about ... 1/2 ... for ranges that need a some more heavy computing, but also taking into account how other PLs handle the `Range` (data) type, one might think of implementing `range` as [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). Thus invoking the above example's `range`, like with `range(0, 20, 5)`, would return a [`Generator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator).

Comment: ... 2/2 ... In case of the OP's use case which explicitly states the word ***sequence*** and also, as result, does return the full sequence (and not a real range type) within an array envelop, one just would write ... `Array.from(range(0, 20, 5))` ... or ... `[...range(0, 20, 5)]`.

Comment: Max - posted a "working" solution - still the requirements aren't as transparent as they should be.  Also not sure I love the way the function works as it adapts to the parameters given, instead of throwing exceptions if the parameters are illogical.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to pass the requirements.  I am sure someone can come up with a more eloquent answer. But the tricky parts are related to mostly the step parameter (negative and 0) and backwards movement (end < start) and the fact that it tries to do the "right" thing (stepping from 0 to -3 should not be possible witha step of 1, but it seems to automatically flip the step to be negative [again from reading the tests]).

```js
function range (start, end, step = 1) {
  if (end === undefined && start !== undefined) {
    end = start;
    start = 0;
  }

  // step should be negative if end is less than start
  if (end < start && step > 0) {
     step = step * -1
  }


  // if the step is 0 you will never allocate the correct array length
  const stepSize = (step == 0) ? 1 : step
  const size = Math.abs(Math.ceil((end - start) / stepSize))


  // need to exit if there is nothing to return
  if (size == Infinity) {
    return []
  }

  // step has some really odd behavior (from tests)
  //     specifically a step of 0, which seems to repeat the start?
  const incrementStep = (x, y) =>
        (step == 0) ? start : x + y * step

  return Array(size).
    fill(start).
    map(incrementStep)
}

console.log(range(4)); // => [0, 1, 2, 3]
console.log(range(-4)); // => [0, -1, -2, -3]
console.log(range(1, 5)); // => [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(range(0, 20, 5)); // => [0, 5, 10, 15]
console.log(range(0, -4, -1)); // => [0, -1, -2, -3]
console.log(range(1, 4, 0)); // => [1, 1, 1]
console.log(range(0)); // => []
```

Comment: range(5,2,5) => fail

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov - its been a long time since I looked at this and it doesn't surprise me this isn't meeting all expectations.  (5,2,5) wasn't one of the original test cases posed by the question asker... what might we expect that to return an empty array?

Comment: I just wanted to say that your example is not an analogue of the Lodash range method. But your code and solution are still great!